# accessing non-static method from another class without instantiate

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, class

Title is my question. I will explain below.

I am working on wpf application is vs2010. I have two windows, one is my MainWindow and another is a fileList window. In my fileList window, I have a list of files, which on click, should load the file. The onClick method is implemented in fileList class. The function to load the file is implemented in MainWindow partial class.

My fileList class in instantiated in MainWindow class to show the window. I cant instantiate MainWidow again. The function(method) in MainWindow can't be declared static because it uses  other parameter which I can't (don't know how to) declared static.

I am pasting relevant code below. Kindly help.

```
namespace test
{
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
     fileList fl = new fileList;

     public MainWindow()
     {
      InitializeComponent();
      fl.show();
      }

      public void porcessfile(string path)
      {
       //this method processes the the file at "path". It uses combobox and scrollviewer 
       //declared in xaml. I dont know how to declare static in xaml, else I will declare       
       //them static and change the whole method to static, so I can call it without  
       //instantiating. I tried making a nested-class, but then I can't  access variable 
       //declared in MainWindow (parent) class. Or there is a way to do that?

      }
}
```

and the other class:

```
namespace test
{
  public partial class fileList : Window
  {
     public fileList()
     {
        IntializeComponent();
     }



     private void Button_click(object sender, RoutedEventsArgs e)
     {
      //code that gets "path" on click, works fine.

      processfile(string path); // what and how to do here.
     }
  }

}
```

I sincerely hope I am clear. Please ask details if required.

Comment: You need to make the class `static`, if you want to access the class methods without object.

Comment: I know that. but then I need to change too much code. and I dont know how to declare a new combobox in xaml as static, because datacontext is set for combobox which is changed my porcessfile method.

Comment: yeah. that wont work because I have binding which are set in MainWindow, and properties are changed by processfile method. I have to pass a lot of things to new class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this should be fairly easy. You just need to declare an event in your FileList class which fires in your Button_click method sending the file path and subscribe to it from MainWindow, and call your processfile method with the argument you've just received.

In your FileList class:

```
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs<string>> PathReceived = delegate { };
```

Publish this in your Button_click.

In your MainWindow class on cosntructor:

```
   this.fileList.PathReceived = (o,args) => this.ProcessFile(args.Value);
```

Publish code:

```
   this.PathReceived(null, new EventArgs<string>(yourPath));
```

**EDIT:**
I forgot to provide you with the EventArgs class (it's from an old project of mine).

```
public class EventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="EventArgs{T}"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    public EventArgs(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The value.
    /// </value>
    public T Value { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: I tried what you said. Its not that simple. Say, i got my path in MainWindow, that is easy. But then I need to invoke another method that will use that path. then it gets ugly. I am not en expert, if you can elaborate, may be I am missing something very fundamental.

Comment: Let me know if this works now. Also don't forget you can always declare the event static if you don't want to instantiate your FileList class.

Comment: Error: The type 'string' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEventArgs' in the generic type or method 'System.EventHandler<TEventArgs>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'string' to 'System.EventArgs'.

Comment: well, i changed string to eventargs. But I am not clear on delegates. reading up.

Comment: Check the updated code. I missed an EventArgs<string> on event declaration. Also when handling the event you should receive your string in the args.Value property.

Comment: <EventArgs<string>> Error:The non-generic type 'System.EventArgs' cannot be used with type arguments

Comment: `EventArgs<T>` should be part of the framework IMO - I find myself using it plenty and when starting a new project wondering why it's not there in the first place...

Comment: works. delegates. i will spend all day on how they work. thanks a ton.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the easiest solution would be to simply give your Filelist window a constructor which accepts an delegate which points to your processfile method in the Mainwindows.
Look at this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/109000/C-Delegates-Step-by-Step

Making it statis is not the solution -it would be a very ugly hack, which causes more trouble than the delegate.

Comment: I will go through the link. Thanks.

Comment: yes, delegate was the way to go. thanks. i accepted the code below, coz the guy actually coded, reading on delegates

Comment: Great article on delegates. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a static convenience access property for all windows in your application:

[Application.Current.Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.windows.aspx)

Then simply take the first one (or figure out the right one if you have more then one) and cast to your `MainWindow` type. And now you have an instance to call your method.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's something of an anti-pattern (because it resembles global variables and persists state, which makes testing more difficult), you can use the singleton pattern here:

```
public partial class MainWindow {
  private static MainWindow instance = new MainWindow();

  public static MainWindow Instance { get { return instance; } }

  private FileList fl = new fileList();

  private MainWindow() {
    InitializeComponent();
    fl.show();
  }
}
```

Your file list can then use `MainWindow.Instance`.

But, this has the side-effect of partially hiding dependencies between the two classes. What you really want to do is require a `MainWindow` instance in the constructor to `fileList`. That keeps the dependencies obvious, and opens the door to using a framework (which will help you with testability).

Also, the C# convention is to call the class `FileList` and not `fileList`.

Comment: I tried it. didnt work. In fact I got two windows of filelist. I can try constructing mainwindows instance in filelist, but then again, the problem can be opposite way, we are just flipping coins in that case.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're doing. It sounds like you need two-way references between both classes, and `static` is just a work-around. I recommend what I said in my answer: prefer to pass references over using static.

Comment: yes. ref is one way. i used delegates, it worked for me. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I do this to get a method to run inside one of my class's without doing the whole variable setup.

```
string res = (new myClass ()).methodInsideMyclass ();
```